# Find all tables in database By primaryKey

Tags: sql

I'm searching for a query that can retrieve all the tables by the specified key/keys name on a specific database.
Something like this:

```
SELECT table_name 
FROM   information_Schema.columns 
WHERE  column_name='ID_UNICO' 
AND    Constraint_Type = 'PRIMARY KEY'
```

I've been searching and the best I could find was:

```
SELECT Col.Column_Name from 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS Tab, 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE Col 
WHERE 
    Col.Constraint_Name = Tab.Constraint_Name
    AND Col.Table_Name = Tab.Table_Name
    AND Constraint_Type = 'PRIMARY KEY'
    AND Col.Table_Name = '<your table name>'
```

this retrieves the PK's of a specific table, I want to find table_name BY PK name.

```
SELECT table_name 
FROM   information_Schema.columns 
WHERE  column_name='ID_UNICO' 
and    ordinal_position = 1;
```

also found this but this gives me the first column of the table, which doesn't ensure me that it it the PK.

Couldn't find any duplicate either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this query. Replace 'YOUR_COLUMN_NAME' with your primary key column name.

```
SELECT Table_Name
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA + '.' + QUOTENAME(CONSTRAINT_NAME)), 'IsPrimaryKey') = 1
and COLUMN_NAME ='YOUR_COLUMN_NAME'
```

Comment: thank you for your help, is is short and simple ! had to set this as the best answer because it is actually less complex

Answer (score 2):

Would this work for you?

```
DECLARE @ColName AS VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @ColName = 'CourseId'
SELECT
    TABLE_NAME
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE
    COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME), COLUMN_NAME, 'IsIdentity') = 1
    AND COLUMN_NAME = @ColName
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, join TABLE_CONSTRAINTS to CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE to tie the constraint name to the column then return your TABLE_NAME:

```
SELECT CCU.COLUMN_NAME, 
       CONS.TABLE_NAME 
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE CCU 
       JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS CONS 
         ON CONS.CONSTRAINT_NAME = CCU.CONSTRAINT_NAME 
WHERE  CONS.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY' 
       AND CCU.COLUMN_NAME = 'ID_UNICO'
```